# Redux action not firing onclick

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Doing a redux todo to learn and having trouble on the toggle todo.

When i trigger the onclick i get an error in the console.

"Failed prop type: The prop `items` is marked as required in `ItemsList`, but its value is `undefined`."

and

"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on items.length

I've consoled logged the action and it seems to be returning the state. not sure what i'm doing wrong. code is below.

actions

```
export const addItem = content => {
  return { type: ADD_ITEM, content };
};

export const toggleTodo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_TODO,
    id,
  };
};
```

my initial state is:

```
       import { ADD_ITEM, TOGGLE_TODO } from './constants';

let nextId = 4;

export const initialState = {
  items: [
    { id: 1, content: 'Call mum', completed: false},
    { id: 2, content: 'Buy cat food', completed: true },
    { id: 3, content: 'Water the plants', completed: false },
  ],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log("action", action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      const newItem = {
        id: nextId++,
        content: action.content,
        completed: false
      };

      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, newItem],
      };
    case TOGGLE_TODO:
      return state.items.map(todo => {
            console.log("state", state);
            console.log("state.items", state.items);
            console.log("todo",todo);
            if (todo.id !== action.id) {
              return state;
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                completed: !todo.completed,
          };
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

and my list component is

```
    import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Todo from "../ItemTodo/index"
import { toggleTodo } from "../../logic/actions";
import './styles.css';

export const ItemsList = ({ items, onTodoClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className={'itemsList-ul'}>
        {items.length < 1 && <p id={'items-missing'}>Add some tasks above.</p>}
        {items.map(item =>
          <Todo
            key={item.id}
            {...item}
            onClick={() => onTodoClick(item.id)}
          />
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ItemsList.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onTodoClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { items: state.todos.items };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onTodoClick: id => dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ItemsList);
```

and my todo component is

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Todo = ({onClick, completed, content }) => (
        <li
        onClick={onClick}
        style={{
            textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
        }}
        >
        {content}
        </li>
);

Todo.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    content: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Todo;
```

Create store

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/store';
import Header from './components/Header';
import ItemCreator from './components/ItemCreator';
import ItemsList from './components/ItemsList';
import './app.css';

const store = configureStore();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <div>
            <ItemCreator />
            <ItemsList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;


import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createReducer from './reducers';

const composeEnhancers =
  (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

const configureStore = (initialState = {}) => {
  return createStore(
    createReducer(),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware())
  );
};

export default configureStore;

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../logic/reducer';

export default function createReducer() {
  return combineReducers({
    todos: reducer,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show where you create store, because you have problem with connect : ````return { items: state.todos.items };````, items is empty in your case

Comment: The itemlist code is above. I have ItemsList.propTypes and passing that in. Also it loads the initial state so think props must be set

Comment: @SlawaEremkin i'll update now

Comment: @Adam Can you add the snippet where you combine all reducers?

Comment: @rash.tay thats added above.

Comment: @Adam there is no export for your todos reducer or you don't copy all your code, at least other code looks right

Comment: @SlawaEremkin can you show me where you mean? i think i might have just missed that out in copy paste

Comment: @SlawaEremkin is right. 

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {}

Comment: @rash.tay I'ved edited above, i'm exporting it

Comment: Okay. Everything seems fine.

Comment: @rash.tay yes that could is above and i'm exporting it at the end of the file, export default reducer;

Comment: Yea just saw that. The code seems fine. Figuring out what's going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156161/discussion-between-adam-and-rash-tay).

Comment: Push it on a GitHub or whatever and provide a link. I'm sure the problem is very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but I think this part is incorrect `TOGGLE_TODO`:

```
  return state.items.map(todo => {
        console.log("state", state);
        console.log("state.items", state.items);
        console.log("todo",todo);
        if (todo.id !== action.id) {
          return state;
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            completed: !todo.completed,
      };
  });
```

it should be:

```
return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === action.id) {
            return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed };
        }
        return todo;
    })
};
```

Comment: That’s fixed it and I see why. Cause I have the items nested in a list in the state.